# EF Core 2.0 For Self Referencing Table / Model

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a component module models which can have many children of its type. So I declare like

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CRSApp.API.Models
{
    /**
        List of Module component in application.!--
        Level 0 means main menu
        Level 1 means submenu        
     */
    public class ModuleComponent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public string ModuleName { get; set; }        
        public int Level { get; set; }        
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public ModuleComponent Parent { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ModuleComponent> Children {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Level 0 ModComponent has no parent (null), but Level 1 have a parent and may not have Children. 
I have no idea how to declare the Fluent API in DataContext for this module. Please help

Thank you

note: I use asp dotnet core 2.x and ef core 2.0

at the moment in DataContextDb.OnModelCreating i Just declare

```
builder.Entity<ModuleComponent>()
               .HasMany(x => x.Children)
               .WithOne( x => x.Parent)
               .HasForeignKey ( x => x.ParentId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Is it enough ?

Comment: Do you get an exception or an unexpected behavior?

Comment: Enough from modeling standpoint. Will require special code for deleting.